# Switching a control from one type to another?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to properly word the title, but here is the situation:

We have a massive solution with about 130 projects in it. There are some redundancies in code, namely a particular `LookupButton` control we've created. For some reason, instead of being created in the `Infrastructure.CommonControls` project that all modular projects reference, this `LookupButton` was created numerous times in the various modules. Quickly poking around through a few of the projects, I found 5 different versions of this control but the **only** difference is its namespace. All of the code is 100% the same.

I've been tasked with creating one of these `LookupButton`s in the aforementioned `Infrastructure.CommonControls` project, and then removing all duplicates from the Module projects.

How can I do this while causing minimal blowback in all of the Designer.cs files that will be looking for `MyModule1.LookupButton`, `MyModule2.LookupButton` etc.  ? I know I have a backup with SVN but I'm afraid to even start and get inundated with errors...

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

- Ensure you have the current state in SVN
- Add the code to Infrastructure.CommonControls
- Remove the code from all projects that it does not belong in
- Compile the solution
- Go through all of the errors.  For each occurrence of LookupButton errors, right-click on LookupButton in source control, pick Resolve, and select the option to add a using statement.

You should only find yourself correcting the 5 projects that had their own internal copy of the control, not all 130.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing is to just remove the redundancies from one project, then fix the compile errors in that project until it compiles again.
Push your new code to the SVN and then move on to the next project. There isn't much else you can do.